# The type or namespace name 'SelectListItem' could not be found, MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to fill the dropdownlist from the database,

I am following this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/681742/How-to-fill-dropdown-in-ASP-NET-MVC-3)

I have written the following code in the model

```
public class FillDeptName
{
    public IList<SelectListItem> Drp_Name { get; set; }
}
```

I am getting the following error message:

> The type or namespace name 'SelectListItem' could not be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are missing on top of your code:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlistitem(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: `SelectListItem` is a class, not a namespace, so your code won't work. Should `using System.Web.Mvc` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Import this namespace

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
```

[FOR MORE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlistitem%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

If the solution is created using NuGet package, it is necessary to add NuGet - "Microsoft Asp.Net MVC" namespace also to your current project.
To add it proceed as follows:
Right click on Solution, select "Manage NUGET packages for solution ..." then find "Microsoft Asp.Net MVC" in the list.
Right click on it and choose "Manage". 
A list with all projects contained into solution will be displayed.
This list has also a checkbox for each project.
If this is checked means that the project use "Microsoft Asp.Net MVC", else not.
Check the checkbox correspondent to your current project.
The namespace will be added to your project and you'll find also "SelectListItem".

Good luck !

Answer (score 1):

[SelectListItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlistitem) belongs to the [System.Web.Mvc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc) namespace, you' ll need to import it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use the namespace using system.web.mvc;

Make conform that in dropdown box you have to give "SelectListItem" in some time most of the people make small mistake in writing this.Correct it